# What are the exoskeletons in Heart x Hybrid (Masou Gakuen) called?

Tags: masou-gakuen

What are the exoskeletons in Heart x Hybrid (Masou Gakuen) called?

I tried looking on the net and on the wikia for this anime and I don't find much about them.

I'm talking about the exoskeletons that are in the background from time to time, not the Hybrid Gears.

You can see it in the background:
[image: You can see it in the background]

You can see them clearly here:
[image: more exoskeletons]